# How to get value from timer that already start before touch event?

Tags: android, timer, touch, andengine

I'm want to make a countdown timer that return value(seconds left) when a touch performed in android. Problem is I use andengine so that the touch event cannot be used inside the method(correct me if I'm wrong).

```
scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(new IOnSceneTouchListener() {
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene scene, TouchEvent arg1) {

    int counterInt = 60;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    counterText.setText(""+counterInt);
    timer.wait(1000);
    counterText.setText(""+(counterInt-1));
    timer.wait(1000);
    counterText.setText(""+(counterInt-1));
    timer.wait(1000);
    counterText.setText(""+(counterInt-1));
    }
}
```

let say default number of counterInt is 60 and its decrease by seconds. When it shows 50 user touch the screen which means activate the touchevent arg1, how I can get the value of counterInt that has '50'? Thank you...

Comment: The timer does absolutely nothing until you schedule a timerTask, in which is where the counterText.setText would go. I'm not sure about andengine tho

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I try timertask later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something like that you want the remaining seconds than its better to use [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). Its `onTick()` gives you the exact time left in the timer started and also you can do any stuff when the countdown finishes inside the `onFinish()`.

Comment: @epndkempt If you think his anwser is correct you should click on the answer button underneath his awnser score. He'l recieve points and the question will be marked answered.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a way easier solution using AndEngine's framework. I've created this simple class for you: [here](http://pastebin.com/6SmaCWsy). Create an instance of it, and register it in your scene:

```
TimeCounter tc = new TimeCounter();
scene.registerUpdateHandler(tc);
```

It will start counting from that moment. Then, you can freely call `tc.getSeconds()` to find out how many seconds passed, and subtract them from any constant value to simulate a countdown.

You can also call `reset` to reset the seconds.